# compact perturbation of diagonalizable operator

Tags: diagonalization, compact-operators, perturbation-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, $A:D(A) \subset H \rightarrow H$ be an unbounded linear operator and $K \in L(H)$ be a compact operator.
Let $A_K$ be defined by
$$A_K x=Ax+Kx, \quad x \in D(A_K)=D(A).$$
Assume that:

(1) There exists an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $H$ and a sequence of *distinct* complex numbers $\{\lambda_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\phi_k \in D(A)$ and $A\phi_k=\lambda_k \phi_k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

(2) $|\lambda_k| \to +\infty$ as $k \to +\infty$.

We know that $A_K$ has a compact resolvent (since so has $A$, and $K$ is a bounded perturbation).
In particular it has generalized eigenfunctions, etc.

**My question is:** can we prove that, asymptotically $A_K$ behaves like $A$ ?
For instance, are the following properties true ?

(1') Asymptotically, $A_K$ has only eigenfunctions, and they are of multiplicity one.

(2') If $\{\mu_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ denotes an enumeration of the eigenvalues of $A_K$, then $\mu_k \sim C \lambda_k$ as $k \to +\infty$ ($C>0$ is a constant).

Is it an open problem ? If not, I would appreciate any reference on this (articles/books).
I already know the classics Kato, Dunford-Schwartz, Gohberg-Krein, etc.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you thought about $\lambda_k \approx \ln k$ so the spacing is $\approx 1/k$ ?

Answer (score 2):

A few remarks on the first question: [Weyl's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) says that a compact self-adjoint perturbation of a self-adjoint operator preserves the essential spectrum. This has been generalized to normal operators, and your $A$ is normal if you give it the natural domain $D(A)=\{ \sum c_k\phi_k: \sum\lambda_k |c_k|^2<\infty \}$.

Since $\sigma_{ess}(A)=\emptyset$, this means that indeed $A+K$ will have pure point spectrum, with eigenvalues $|\lambda_n(A+K)|\to\infty$, *if* $K$ is normal, in addition to being compact.

In general, this will not follow: a trivial counterexample is obtained if the eigenvalues of $A$ almost come in pairs, that is, $\lambda_{2n+1}\simeq\lambda_{2n}$. Then a compact perturbation can make them equal to one another, plus you can introduce a non-zero entry in the top right corner of each such $2\times 2$ block, so that you get non-diagonalizable Jordan blocks.

Comment: Thanks, this enlightened me and I could build an explicit counterexample based on what you said.
In particular, this point out that we need some gap condition since the counterexample works because $\lambda_{k+1}-\lambda_k$ goes zero.
However, in many applications we indeed have the gap condition:
$$(G) \quad |\lambda_{k+1}-\lambda_k| \geq \delta>0$$
(think of the Dirichlet Laplacian in 1D on a bounded interval, etc.)
What happens now if we add the condition (G) to the assumption (1) ?
I think (1') becomes true.

Comment: @perturbation: I'm not sure about that, it might work. At least in a finite-dimensional situation this will keep the operator diagonalizable under a small enough perturbation.